# Sorting results by distance in ONGR ElasticsearchDSL

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, geo, symfony3.x, ongr

I'm using ONGR ElasticsearchDSL Bundle together with Symfony 3 to search through a list of citys by lat/lon coordinates, like so:

```
$repository = $this->elasticsearchManager->getRepository(CityDocument::class);
$search = $repository->createSearch();

$boolQuery = new BoolQuery();
$boolQuery->add(new MatchAllQuery());
$geoQuery = new GeoDistanceQuery('geo', '50km', $theSearch['location']);
$boolQuery->add($geoQuery, BoolQuery::FILTER);
$search->addQuery($boolQuery);
$documents = $repository->findDocuments($search);
```

While this gives me a good result with matching cities, I am unclear on how to sort those by distance from my source point (found in $theSearch['location']), so that I get them ordererd from closest to farthest?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to use ElasticsearchDSL including sort you need.

```
$repository = $this->elasticsearchManager->getRepository(CityDocument::class);
$search = $repository->createSearch();

$geoQuery = new GeoDistanceQuery('geo', '50km', $theSearch['location']);
$search->addQuery($geoQuery, BoolQuery::FILTER);

$sort = new FieldSort('_geo_distance', null, [
    'geo' => $geoLocation,
    'order' => 'asc',
    'unit' => 'km',
    'mode' => 'min',
    'distance_type' => 'arc'
]);
$search->addSort($sort);

$documents = $repository->findDocuments($search);
```

Comment: When I use your code as is I get a "No mapping found for [location] in order to sort on". But that's expected, since my location field is actually called "geo", not "location". But if I switch it, I instead get an "can't sort on geo_point field without using specific sorting feature, like geo_distance". So apparently FieldSort needs some extra params? But I don't really know which.

Comment: Yes, geo_distance is completely different sort. As described here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#geo-sorting you need to pass all parameters to the `FieldSort`

You can still use `FieldSort('_geo_distance', null, ['all params array'])` with `_geo_distance` field and you need to pass all parameters in the third variable.

Comment: Cool, @saimaz, you pushed me in the right direction. I edited your answer, so that it fits my question and will now set it as the correct answer. Thanks for your help!